# Link to jQuery UI tab from external page and set tab to active

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I have a site using jQuery UI tabs and link to a specific tab from external pages using something like

```
<a href="/tabspage#tab-3">
```

and this correctly opens the proper panel, but it does not give the actual tab the proper classes like ui-tabs-active or ui-state-active.

I have tried some custom scripting to find the index of the active panel and then go find the corresponding tab and add the classes to it, but then clicking on another tab does not remove those classes from the initial active class.

Is it possible to link to a specific jQuery UI tab and also make the tab of the opened panel highlighted?

Comment: If you're linking from another page, this does not tell `.tabs()` which tab to open. You can look at the URL and see if `#tab-3` is included in the URL and then during or after initialization, you can make `#tab-3` active.

Comment: OK. I think I will try that. Search for the tab in the url and use the enable(index) method to enable that tab (even though that panel is already open, I'm hopeful that will highlight the tab at the top).